# How to disable all enabled APIs/Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Whenever I create a new Project in GCP, it comes preloaded with a host of APIs/Services I don't want:

```
BigQuery API                    
BigQuery Migration API                  
BigQuery Storage API                    
Cloud Datastore API                 
Cloud Debugger API                  
...
```

How can I quickly disable all these? I've tried using the UI to do it, but that's a lot of clicking and waiting. Is there a faster and easily repeatable way?

P.S. I'm pretty sure I don't need these, but why does Google preload them, and seemingly so many?

Comment: FYI: Do not disable API services if you do not understand what they do and why they are enabled. There is no cost to having an API enabled.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thank you for that suggestion. I was thinking along those lines, too. I just need a Cloud Function that can simply receive an HTTP GET and display a URL param in the body of the response; and the console prompted me to install the necessary APIs, some of which I had just deleted. I don't want to fear the defaults, and I looked and couldn't find any explanation of the defaults and why.

Comment: @JohnHanley, also, I was working with another API the other day, and I thought it was enabled in my project but it wasn't, and the resulting error message made it very clear I needed to go in an enable the API in the project. Are some failures less obvious? Thanks again for sharing from your 14+ yrs experience w/cloud platforms.

Comment: You will need to study each API and the services those APIs provide to know. Some are critical and others are service specific. If your goal is a deep understanding of Google Cloud, invest the time. Google is constantly releasing new services and new features that change which APIs are available, enabled, etc. With experience, you will know what to look for and how to resolve oddball issues.

Answer (score 4):

I dug around in the documentation and pieced together this one-liner that I can run from the Cloud Shell Editor:

```
gcloud services list --format="value(config.name)" \
| xargs -I{} gcloud services disable --force {}
```

`config.name` was not obvious at first, and reading the whole JSON output was too much.  I found this command to help understand the keys:

```
gcloud services list --format text --limit 1
---
config.authentication:        {}
config.documentation.summary: A data platform for customers to create, manage, share and query data.
config.monitoring:            {}
config.name:                  bigquery.googleapis.com
config.quota:                 {}
config.title:                 BigQuery API
config.usage.requirements[0]: serviceusage.googleapis.com/tos/cloud
name:                         projects/1036866263612/services/bigquery.googleapis.com
parent:                       projects/1036866263612
state:                        ENABLED
```

`--force` wasn't obvious at first either, and I got this error when I ran the one-liner without it:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.services.disable) FAILED_PRECONDITION: The service bigquery.googleapis.com is depended on by the following active service(s): bigquerystorage.googleapis.com,cloudapis.googleapis.com; Please specify disable_dependent_services=true if you want to proceed with disabling all services.
Help Token: Acz52G35wwAHic2MVFBydEf3GnUW8kGOFsau4WeUP72xPGrnZDlWAiUu5HD8AtOxQk0gv0my6uzVEXnampf1_NqXamrmHQWUwSkgOrw6ybqxTd7R
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure
  violations:
  - subject: ?error_code=100001&service_name=bigquery.googleapis.com&services=bigquerystorage.googleapis.com&services=cloudapis.googleapis.com
    type: googleapis.com
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: serviceusage.googleapis.com
  metadata:
    service_name: bigquery.googleapis.com
    services: bigquerystorage.googleapis.com,cloudapis.googleapis.com
  reason: COMMON_SU_SERVICE_HAS_DEPENDENT_SERVICES
```

`disable_dependent_services=true` didn't show up in the `gcloud services disable --help`, but the description of `--force` made clear that I should use that option.

Comment: `gcloud` uses Google's REST APIs and you may determine which API methods by appending `--log-http` to any command. In this case `gcloud services foo` uses the [Services Usage API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest) and, if you look at the [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/get) method, you'll see these return [Service](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services#Service) objects which is what you found with `--format`. That's how to generically solve that problem.

Comment: I encourage you to consider providing a list of services to disable rather than the current `disable everything` approach. Disabling everything may work today but could break tomorrow. If you know you'll never need `Cloud Datastore API` then disabling it explicitly feels safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project which I only use for translations. I have multiple sources and felt that disabling the api's in the project is the safest way. Sure one can restrict the API key to utilize only the translations google api, however if a new api key is added and the admin skips the restriction step. The api key could be used to do everything in the project.

Here is what i've done thus launching cloud console

```
 #!/bin/bash

# List all services that are enabled on the project
enabled_services=$(gcloud services list --enabled --format="value(config.name)")

# Loop through the list of enabled services
for service in $enabled_services; do
    if [ "$service" != "translate.googleapis.com" ]; then
        echo "Disabling $service..."
        gcloud services disable $service --quiet
    else
        echo "Skipping Cloud Translation API..."
    fi
done

echo "All services except Cloud Translation API have been disabled."
```